# How can I find out how much memory my graphics card has on Red Hat 2.6.18?

Tags: graphics-card, redhat-enterprise-linux

I tried searching and googling, but I could not figure out how to figure out the specs on my graphics card. Is there a command or a menu I can use to access this information? BTW it is a Nvidia card, I believe and 8 series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the proprietary drivers, try running `nvidia-settings`.  If not, run `lspci -v` and it *should* be on a line like this in your video card section:

```
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
```

Unfortunately, on my computer at least this does not work right, as my video card has 512 megabytes of RAM.

Comment: I find it funny that the top (and accepted) answer is one that the answerer admitted doesn't even work for him.  :-)

Comment: Ironic I know, but I found several other sites suggesting it, so I thought it might help him even if it didn't work for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use lspci to find out what the exact model of the video card is, and then look it up online...

```
[12:34pm][wlynch@node ~] lspci | grep "3D controller"
04:00.0 3D controller: nVidia Corporation GF100 [Tesla S2050] (rev a3)
05:00.0 3D controller: nVidia Corporation GF100 [Tesla S2050] (rev ff)
08:00.0 3D controller: nVidia Corporation GF100 [Tesla S2050] (rev ff)
09:00.0 3D controller: nVidia Corporation GF100 [Tesla S2050] (rev ff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the X11 log.  Mine is at /var/log/Xorg.0.log, and part of it looks like this (I'm running a VM):

```
(II) VBoxVideo(0): VESA BIOS detected
(II) VBoxVideo(0): VESA VBE Version 2.0
(II) VBoxVideo(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 131072 kB
(II) VBoxVideo(0): VESA VBE OEM: VirtualBox VBE BIOS http://www.virtualbox.org/
(II) VBoxVideo(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 0.2
```

131072 KB = 128 MB, which is exactly what I've set in the VM settings.